# STL container with different contained types?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

Let's say I have different types of components which are structs. Maybe I have `TransformComponent` and `RigidBodyComponent`

Now, this is the problem: I want something like an `std::map` where you map a component type and an id to a component. The ids are what links components together. What kind of container should I use for this? I can't use an `std::map<std::typeindex, std::map<id_t, T>>` since the type `T` depends on which typeindex you use to index the first map.

Comment: Do `TransformComponent` and `RigidBodyComponent` have similar interfaces? If so, you can derive them from common base class and store smart pointers to the instances.

Comment: They are plain old data types, not related to each other at all really.

Comment: Your question does not provide enough info, answer would depend on why you want to store 2 unrelated data types in one container and how you want to access that data.

Comment: In general, the STL standard containers are homogeneous; they all store items of a single type. You can relax that somewhat with inheritance and storing pointers.

Comment: Oh well, maybe I'll store pointers to the inner containers then.

Comment: Put the question of *which* aside for a moment. Suppose you can have such a container. *What* will you do with it? Can you show some intended usage examples?

Comment: I want to be able to do two things. First, index it with a type and id and get a value out. Second thing I want to do is to iterate through all structs of a single type.

Answer (score 1):

Your use case sounds like a typical use of polymorphism. You should know that any attempts to store "non-homogenous" types in a single container will come with the performance penalty of polymorphism. As of whether you will use "out of the box" polymorphism that C++ provides or go for a custom solution - its entirely up to you.

BTW, to cite one of the questions from the comments on the question:

> Suppose you can have such a container. What will you do with it? Can
>   you show some intended usage examples?

This is a very good question, because revealing your particular usage scenario will allow other to answer your question in much more detail, because right now it sounds like you don't really know what you are doing or need to do. So, if you need further guidance, you should really clarify and build on your question.

Comment: I essentially want to make an entity system (http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/09/03/entity-systems-are-the-future-of-mmog-development-part-1/).

Comment: There is an example implementation - http://entity-systems.wikidot.com/test-for-parallel-processing-of-components#cpp also you might want to read a bit on Data orientation and data oriented design.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with container which contain different types, look on some BOOST libraries:
**Any**: Safe, generic container for single values of different value types. (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any.html)
**Variant**: Safe, generic, stack-based discriminated union container (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html)

Use **variant**, if list of your types is well defined and does not change.

So your code can look like this:

```
typedef boost::variant<TransformComponent, RigidBodyComponent> my_struct;
std::map<std::typeindex, std::map<id_t, my_struct> > cont;
...
std::typeindex index = std::type_index(typeid(TransformComponent));
std::map<id_t, my_struct> & m = cont[index];
id_t id = ...;
TransformComponent & component = boost::get<TransformComponent>(m[id]);
```

This code is quite ugly, so think about changing architecture. May be it will simpler with boost::any or with boost::variant.

P.S.
If you write template code then may be better to look to boost::mpl.

Answer (score 0):

So you can solve this if you don't mind writing a custom container that uses ye olde C hacking.

I've written you an example here:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct ent
{
    int myInt;
};

struct floats
{
    float float1;
    float float2;
};

struct container
{
    bool isTypeFloats;

    union
    {
        ent myEnt;
        floats myFloats;
    };
};

void main( void )
{
    ent a = { 13 };
    floats b = { 1.0f, 2.0f };
    container c;
    container d;

    cout << b.float1 << " " << b.float2 << endl;

    c.isTypeFloats = false;
    c.myEnt = a;

    d.isTypeFloats = true;
    d.myFloats = b;

    //correct accessor
    if( c.isTypeFloats )
    {
        cout << c.myFloats.float1 << " " << c.myFloats.float2 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << c.myEnt.myInt << endl;
    }

    if( d.isTypeFloats )
    {
        cout << d.myFloats.float1 << " " << d.myFloats.float2 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << d.myEnt.myInt << endl;
    }
}
```

To put these structs in a container you'd just do: `std::vector< container >`

A couple things you should know about this:

1. unions allocate space for the largest type. So in my example if an int takes 4 bytes and a float takes 4 bytes, then even when I'm storing just an `ent` it will allocate space for a `floats` so I'll be wasting 4 bytes each time I'm storing an `ent`. Depending on the purpose of your application and the size of the types you're storing this may be negligible.
2. If there is a significant disparity in size in the types you're storing then you can go about this the way C++ is really handling the union under the hood. And that's to use a `void*`. So you would do: `std::vector< void* > myVec` and you would insert like this: `myVec.push_back( &x )` where `x` is your type, for example the `ent` from our example. But reading it out you'd have to know what you were pointing at so you'd have to know to do something like: `cout << ( ( ent* )myVec[0] )->myInt << endl;`
3. Because you probably wouldn't know what type it was unless you had some predefined writing pattern you'd probably just end up wanting to use a container struct like so:

   struct container2
   {
       bool isTypeFloats;
       void* myUnion;
   }

Answer (score 0):

How about boost::any  or   boost::any_cast ??

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any.html